# Не подгружает контент при скроле

Tags: vue.js

День добрый!
Я использовал этот пример https://jsfiddle.net/PeachScript/a4Lxbf9w/
но когда перенес к себе в компонент, он не подгружает контент более 20 строк.
В чем может быть проблема?

Вот мой код компонента:

```
<template>
  <ion-content id="content" class="ion-page ion-padding content-bg content-offset ion-text-center">
    <div
      class="hacker-news-item"
      v-for="(item, $index) in list"
      :key="$index"
      :data-num="$index + 1">
      <a target="_blank" :href="item.url" v-text="item.title"></a>
      <p>
        <span v-text="item.points"></span>
        points by
        <a
          target="_blank"
          :href="`https://news.ycombinator.com/user?id=${item.author}`"
          v-text="item.author"></a>
        |
        <a
          target="_blank"
          :href="`https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=${item.objectID}`"
          v-text="`${item.num_comments} comments`"></a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <infinite-loading @infinite="infiniteHandler"></infinite-loading>
  </ion-content>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  import InfiniteLoading from 'vue-infinite-loading';
  const api = '//hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=story';

  export default {
    name: 'Settings',
    components: {
      InfiniteLoading,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        page: 1,
        list: [],
      };
    },
    methods: {
      infiniteHandler($state) {
        axios.get(api, {
          params: {
            page: this.page,
          },
        }).then(({ data }) => {
          if (data.hits.length) {
            this.page += 1;
            this.list.push(...data.hits);
            $state.loaded();
          } else {
            $state.complete();
          }
        });
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: что говорит вкладка `Network`?

Comment: нетворк говорит что все ок, отправил запрос, получил данные, а вот при прокрутке нового запроса не отправляет

Comment: Рискну предположить что стили за ним Вы не перенесли. Скорее всего "хендлер" схлопнулся. Либо же у Вас в верстке поломан `overflow` посмотрите документацию о [forceUseInfiniteWrapper](https://peachscript.github.io/vue-infinite-loading/api/#forceuseinfinitewrapper), eсли это решение не поможет посмотрите это [issue](https://github.com/PeachScript/vue-infinite-loading/issues/122) о flex.